# Using the geometric distribution to find the probability that between 4 and 6 devices will be tested

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Quality control tests spark plugs until they find one that doesn't work. If the probability of a spark plug working is 0.99, what is the probability that they will test between 4 and 6 (inclusive) spark plugs?

This is a geometric probability distribution, $X =$ number of successes before failure, $P(X = x) = p^x
(1 – p)$

I thought the answer would be $P(X =4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)=.99^4*.01+.99^5*.01+.99^6*.01$ but the answer key says that it is actually $P(X =3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)=.99^3*.01+.99^4*.01+.99^5*.01$. Why is that? Why is it between 3 and 5 rather than 4 and 6?

Comment: Because the number of spark plugs tested isn't $x$, but is $x+1$.

Comment: Where does it say that in the problem? Or is that just like a rule for geometric probability problems?

Comment: You have it right there, "X= number of successes before failure". So the total number tested is X+1

Comment: If they "test 4 spark plugs" and stop, they will have *success,success,success,fail*.  I.e., "testing 4 sparkplugs and stopping" is equivalent to "getting 3 successes before failure"

Comment: Oooh that makes sense. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, $1$ test is equivalent to $x=0$, since none of the plugs would succeed. Likewise, $4$ tests means $x=3$ and $6$ tests means $x=5$. Since you know the probability distribution function, you just want to sum this over values from $x=3$ to $x=5$ (inclusive). This gives the answer that the answer key has.